# SiriKit crashes: "Use of the class from an app requires the entitlement com.apple.developer.siri."

Tags: sirikit

We have been receiving crash reports say that "*Use of the class INPreferences from an app requires the entitlement com.apple.developer.siri. Did you enable the Siri capability in your Xcode project?*".  But We have **absolutely** enabled the Siri capability in Xcode, and the APP ID *does* support the Siri feature, otherwise our app would have crashed all the time.  So, why just some devices crashed? This bothers us a lot.

Anyone knows the reason or has encoutered the same problem?  We'd appreciate if you can offer some help.

Here is the crash log:

```
0 CoreFoundation 0x000000018b6fd1b8 ___exceptionPreprocess + 124  
1 libobjc.A.dylib 0x000000018a13455c objc_exception_throw + 44  
2 Intents 0x00000001a4cd55ac -[INPreferences _siriAuthorizationStatus]  
3 libdispatch.dylib 0x000000018a5861bc __dispatch_client_callout + 16  
4 libdispatch.dylib 0x000000018a586fb0 dispatch_once_f + 56  
5 Intents 0x00000001a4cd51d8 -[INPreferences assertThisProcessHasSiriEntitlement] + 112  
6 Intents 0x00000001a4cd57f8 -[INPreferences requestSiriAuthorization:] + 96  
7 Intents 0x00000001a4cd5950 +[INPreferences requestSiriAuthorization:] + 80  
8 AppName 0x0000000100589cf4 -[AppDelegate _requestAuthorizations] (CAppDelegate.m:802)  
9 AppName 0x00000001001b99dc -[SplashView p_didTransitionImageViewAnimations] (SplashView.m:234)  
10 AppName 0x0000000100a3adb0 -[SplashView p_disappearImageView] (SplashView.m:395)  
11 Foundation 0x000000018c1fa46c __NSFireDelayedPerform + 416  
12 CoreFoundation 0x000000018b6ab1d8 ___CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 28  
13 CoreFoundation 0x000000018b6aaeec ___CFRunLoopDoTimer + 872   
14 CoreFoundation 0x000000018b6aa7a8 ___CFRunLoopDoTimers + 244  
15 CoreFoundation 0x000000018b6a83a4 ___CFRunLoopRun + 1572  
16 CoreFoundation 0x000000018b5d62b8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 436  
17 GraphicsServices 0x000000018d08a198 GSEventRunModal + 172  
18 UIKit 0x00000001916167fc -[UIApplication _run] + 684  
19 UIKit 0x0000000191611534 UIApplicationMain + 204  
20 AppName 0x00000001002a6084 main (main.m:248)  
21 libdyld.dylib 0x000000018a5b95b8 _dyld_process_info_notify_release + 36  

Use of the class <INPreferences: 0x174238980> from an app requires the entitlement com.apple.developer.siri. Did you enable the Siri capability in your Xcode project?
```

Comment: Same issue is happening for me. Is there any specific reason for this. App works fine when it is running directly from XCODE. It crashes when app calls permission request for siri when using an archived build. And no other logs are comming. Once i remove siri permission request, it works fine. And there is no issues for other permissions when request.

Answer (score 3):

Seems like you need to share data of main applciaiton with extension, turn on Siri Capability and App Grouping for your app. Also, you have to add Siri feature for your app on [developer.apple.com](http://developer.apple.com)

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'm confused that if this was the reason, the app would have crashed all the time.  Anyway, I'll try this solution, thx!

Comment: @pikachu try to enable Siri capability for your app as well.

Answer (score 1):

Go to your Entitlements file and make sure you enabled siri

[image]

Comment: This one worked for me. I have enabled Siri in certificates and capabilities still I was getting this error after adding Siri in Entitlements I didn't get any errors