# 'Use of the class <INPreferences: 0x600000cd64a0> from an app requires the entitlement com.apple.developer.siri. Did you enable the Siri

Tags: swift, siri

I working with swift 5 and Xcode 12.
I enabled Siri and add "import Intents" in my ViewController

in the viewdidload:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()

   INPreferences.requestSiriAuthorization { (status) in }
}
```

My app crashs:

```
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Use of the class <INPreferences: 0x600000cd64a0> from an app requires the entitlement com.apple.developer.siri. Did you enable the Siri capability in your Xcode project?'
terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Any idea? :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to `Signing & Capabilities -> Capability -> Siri(double click)` and wait for the provisioning profile to update.

Once you see the `Siri` as shown in the below image then run your project.

[image]

Comment: Please check your [entitlements file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53299209/2395636) if Siri is there. Also verify on developer account if Siri is enabled for the [provisioning](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60666488/2395636).